# \s не реагирует на пробел

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match("/^\s*$/",$_POST['text']);
```

Нужно отловить сообщения которые состоят только из пробелов, переводов строк или пустые.
Пустые и которые состоят только из переводов строк функция замечает, но вот если в строке есть пробелы она не реагирует.
Как правильно написать выражение?

Возвратил строку с пробелами urlencode:

%C2%A0 - один пробел,
%C2%A0%C2%A0 - 2 пробела,
%C2%A0+%C2%A0 - 3 пробела

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас во входящих данных именно пробелы (код 32)?

Зачастую такая фигня бывает, когда вместо обычного пробела стоят &nbsp;, 0xC2A0 и прочая фигня. Т.е. выглядят они как пробелы, но при этом имеют совершенно другое представление. Поэтому \s и не находит их (оно ищет только "настоящий" пробел)

Comment: И кстати, попробуйте добавить модификатор `m`

    "/^\s*$/m"

Comment: Вам конечно виднее, но почему бы простым способом это не сделать?

    $str = " \n \t";
    $str = trim($str);
    if(empty($str)){
 echo 'Пусто';
    }

Comment: А экранировать бэкслеши Заратустра не позволяет? Если так:

     preg_match("/^\\s*$/",$_POST['text'])

Comment: Johny, выражение работает нормально, когда форма отправляется из input или textarea, но я использую блок с contenteditable и отправляю текст через  ajax. Использую str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $_POST['text']); но не помогает. В базу данных пишутся обычные пробелы.

Comment: @TANKIST, сделайте вывод в браузер результата urlencode текста который приходит и укажите его в качестве уточнения вопроса.

Comment: А перед отправкой сообщения, разве нельзя проверить? Или вы не ищите легких путей?

Comment: @deonis, все что проверяется только на клиенте изначально брешь в защите

Comment: @ReinRaus, на "пустоту" проверять на клиенте - это более чем достаточно, я бы даже сказал, что глупо продолжать какие-либо действия, если эта проверка не пройдена. Смысл гонять ajax-запросы и прочее? Посему, не нужно утрировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте флаг unicode:

```
preg_match("/^\\s*$/u", $text);
```

http://ideone.com/1p9hi5

Comment: Не знал про эту фичу с пробелами )) Спасибо! )))

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выражение `preg_match('#^[\s\t\n]*$#', $str)`

Comment: не помогло, на пробелы также не реагирует

Comment: Скиньте код на ideone.com со строкой которая не проходит